# How to create a list with just dataframe names as elements to be used as input for other function call

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop

I'm trying to concatenate multiple csv files with similar file names. The way I want to do it is to write a function and run the function using a for loop.

The function I wrote:

```
def GetEach(LastBit):
    FilePath = r'file:///Path\FLAG_' + LastBit + '.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(FilePath)
    df = df[['CRN', 'ALCOHOL_RELATED', 'CELL_PHONE', 'DRINKING_DRIVER', 'DRUG_RELATED',
       'ILLEGAL_DRUG_RELATED', 'DRUGGED_DRIVER',
       'IMPAIRED_DRIVER' ]]
    return df
```

And then the for loop I wrote is shown below. The reason for the code is that the filenames of the csv files are almost identical, except for different year.

```
for i in range(2, 8):
    MyInput = '201' + str(i) + '_Northampton'
    r.append(GetEach(MyInput))
```

What I want to finally acquire is something like `WhatIWant = [GetEach(2012), GetEach(2013)...]` and then I can just run `pd.concat(WhatIWant )` to get what I want. But apparently my code will make the dataframe totally unravel in the list `r`.

How shall I fix my code? Or is there a much better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You might look into `glob`

Answer (score 1):

This is a good way to read the csv's, append the dataframes to a list and then concat them into 1 big dataframe.

Your code sample is not really complete. Does your code look something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

def GetEach(LastBit):
    FilePath = r'file:///Path\FLAG_' + LastBit + '.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(FilePath)
    df = df[['CRN', 'ALCOHOL_RELATED', 'CELL_PHONE', 'DRINKING_DRIVER', 'DRUG_RELATED', 'ILLEGAL_DRUG_RELATED', 'DRUGGED_DRIVER','IMPAIRED_DRIVER' ]]
    return df 

r = [] # Start with an empty list!

for i in range(2, 8):
    MyInput = '201' + str(i) + '_Northampton'
    r.append(GetEach(MyInput)) 

df_complete = pd.concat(r)
```

If so, have you checked that the individual df's are correct?

Comment: Oh yes! It looked exactly like this except for the last line because I stopped to check `r` and see that `r` didn't show like `[df1, df2, df3 ...]` and thought that didn't work so I just stopped there. Didn't know that it would actually work. Now I'm curious: why would the `pd.concat` function work even when the input was the whole dataframes? Is that just what `pd.concat` does? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's just what pd.concat is for. See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) and look at the examples near the bottum, where they use pd.concat on df1 and df2.

Comment: Gotcha. I thought that the input for `pd.concat` shall always look like `[df1, df2 ...]`. While in my case, the input `r` has the whole dataframes unraveled inside, so I thought it wouldn't work. I guess I was being a little pedantic and gave up a little too early. My bad. Thanks.